# Fabricjs in draggable DIV

Tags: jquery-ui, html, canvas, draggable, fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas within a draggable (jquery-ui) DIV. However, when I drag the div the canvas coordinates get crazy and I cannot anymore interact with it.

Any idea how to prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dragging, let canvas know that you're repositioning it's div:

```
canvas.calcOffset();
```

Comment: Yes that helped. I have however another problem. If I do not drag but append anything to the document and by that shift the position of the canvas the effect is the same. Is there a way to detect that canvas or its container change the position?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if you need to detect+calcOffset when the canvas has re-rendered you can use this:  canvas.on("after:render", function(){ canvas.calcOffset(); });